# VUE 3 - iframe video

Tags: video, iframe, vuejs3

from axios i get iframe video with link:

```
<iframe src="https..." width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen title="Tr&amp;eacute;ning TEXT"></iframe>
```

...**and I need to display this iframe on the page and play video** (the automatic start of the video is not important, I need it only after clicking on the button)

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is that `<iframe...` code what you receive back as text String? Is it received into a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly try like following snippet:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      showFrame: false,
      video: '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qZXt1Aom3Cs" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen title="Tr&amp;eacute;ning TEXT"></iframe>'
    };
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.29/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button @click="showFrame = true">Show</button>
  <div v-html="video" v-show="showFrame"></div>
</div>
```